# Scala compiler build error JComboBox type parameters

Tags: scala, jcombobox, build-error

So I'm trying to compile the scala compiler, I've overcome many problems trying to get this done but I am currently stuck at quick.lib

This is very confusing as the source is taken directly from the scala team themselves so I know it should compile.  Also taken an old version I know compiles elsewhere and tested that but get the same error.

Any help on the issue or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
quick.lib:
[scalacfork] Compiling 103 files to C:\programming\scala\build\quick\classes\library
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ComboBox.scala:162: error: class JComboBox takes type parameters
[scalacfork]   override lazy val peer: JComboBox = new JComboBox(ComboBox.newConstantModel(items)) with SuperMixin
[scalacfork]                           ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ComboBox.scala:123: error: trait ComboBoxModel takes type parameters
[scalacfork]   def newConstantModel[A](items: Seq[A]): ComboBoxModel = {
[scalacfork]                                           ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ComboBox.scala:124: error: trait ComboBoxModel takes type parameters
[scalacfork]     new AbstractListModel with ComboBoxModel {
[scalacfork]                                ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ComboBox.scala:134: error: type mismatch;
[scalacfork]  found   : AnyRef
[scalacfork]  required: Nothing
[scalacfork]       def getElementAt(n: Int) = items(n).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
[scalacfork]                                                       ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ComboBox.scala:162: error: too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
[scalacfork]   override lazy val peer: JComboBox = new JComboBox(ComboBox.newConstantModel(items)) with SuperMixin
[scalacfork]                                           ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:32: error: trait ListCellRenderer takes type parameters
[scalacfork]     def wrap[A](r: ListCellRenderer): Renderer[A] = new Wrapped[A](r)
[scalacfork]                    ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:27: error: class JList takes type parameters
[scalacfork]   def wrap[A](c: JList) = new ListView[A] {
[scalacfork]                  ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:145: error: class JList takes type parameters
[scalacfork]   override lazy val peer: JList = new JList with SuperMixin
[scalacfork]                           ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:37: error: trait ListCellRenderer takes type parameters
[scalacfork]    class Wrapped[A](override val peer: ListCellRenderer) extends Renderer[A] {
[scalacfork]                                             ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:72: error: trait ListCellRenderer takes type parameters
[scalacfork]     def peer: ListCellRenderer = new ListCellRenderer {
[scalacfork]               ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:72: error: trait ListCellRenderer takes type parameters
[scalacfork]     def peer: ListCellRenderer = new ListCellRenderer {
[scalacfork]                                      ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:73: error: class JList takes type parameters
[scalacfork]       def getListCellRendererComponent(list: JList, a: Any, index: Int, isSelected: Boolean, focused: Boolean) = 
[scalacfork]                                              ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:126: error: trait ListCellRenderer takes type parameters
[scalacfork]     override lazy val peer: ListCellRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer
[scalacfork]                             ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:153: error: type mismatch;
[scalacfork]  found   : AnyRef
[scalacfork]  required: Nothing
[scalacfork]     def getElementAt(n: Int) = items(n).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
[scalacfork]                                                     ^
[scalacfork] C:\programming\scala\src\swing\scala\swing\ListView.scala:195: error: too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
[scalacfork]     object indices extends Indices(peer.getSelectedIndices) {
[scalacfork]                    ^
[scalacfork] 15 errors found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using JDK7?   One on the 'issues' is that JDK7 added generics to some of the Swing APIs and this is not compatible with the way scala works. Using JDK6 will help.

A little more about this can be found at: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/01CszZu8ga4/discussion

Comment: I tried to answer this myself yesterday, twice, but it wouldn't let me.  Turns out the fix was to switch to jdk6.  So nice work for getting the correct answer but I got it sorted last night.  Just wish this site would let me answer my own question quicker =p Nice explanation as to why it was happening though.  Now I actually understand why.

Comment: @Blue42, you will loose points upon answering your own question ;)